# Sorting a comma separated list of values

Tags: macos, sorting, shell

What's the easiest way to sort a comma separated list of values in Mac OS X:

Input: "a, b, aaa, bc"

Output: "a, aaa, b, bc"

I'd like to do this from the terminal so that I can pipe the output to another command.

Comment: Is this a full CSV (i.e., records separated by newlines and quoted values can contain commas) or just values delimited by a comma and a space?

Comment: Good question, just values delimited by a comma and space.

Comment: Also, I don't care about case sensitivity for this. So "A" and "a" are considered the same.

Comment: It's looks like a combo of sed + sort + sed will do it, is this the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ echo "a, b, Aaa, bc" |egrep -o "[^, ]+" |sort -f | xargs |sed -e 's/ /, /g'
```

if the values contain spaces:

```
$ echo "a, b, Aaa, bc" |egrep -o "[^, ][^,]*" |sort -f | xargs -I Q echo Q, | xargs
```

but then you get an extra ", " for free at the end.

Comment: `man xargs` is good reading, and connecting it to `find -print0` is also good basic knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "a, b, Aaa, bc"|tr -s "[, ]" "\n"|sort|sed -e :a -e 'N;s/\n/,/;ba'

echo "a, b, Aaa, bc"| tr -s "[, ]" "\n"|sort|tr "\n" ","|sed 's/,$//'
```

Comment: There's something going wrong in the sed portion, I like the use of tr though.

Comment: almost there, except it's losing the space after the comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'a, b, aaa, bc' | awk '{split($0, a, ", "); n = asort(a); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {printf a[i]; if (i<n) printf ", "}}'
```